# What is the difference between a "new" unused dependency and an unused dependency?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dependencies, unattended-upgrades

What is the difference between:

- Remove-**New**-Unused-Dependencies, and
- Remove-Unused-Dependencies,

when performing an unattended upgrade?

The following listing is an excerpt from the the configuration file for unattended upgrades (`/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`) on Ubuntu 20.04.

```
// Do automatic removal of newly unused dependencies after the upgrade
Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-New-Unused-Dependencies "true";

// Do automatic removal of unused packages after the upgrade
// (equivalent to apt-get autoremove)
//Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Dependencies "false";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading through the source, it appears that "Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-New-Unused-Dependencies" will only remove unused dependencies that were created during that unattended-upgrade invocation whereas "Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Dependencies" will remove all unused dependencies, regardless of when they were created.